# Set up facebook UrchinTracker for aJax calls for Google Analytics

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, tracker, urchin

I have set up the Google Analytics in my FBML facebook application. It works for tracking the php pages.  (I can see the report in GA).

However, I also want to track the aJax calls, because most of the pages of my application is ajax driven, rather than loading differnet php pages.

so, that's what I put in the code (before ajax call)

Facebook.urchinTracker('/importantpage/');

THere is no error return when running the application.

However, when I look at the Google Analytics, I can't find any report showing this is being tracked.  I look at the Event tracking.. nothing.   I look at the overview, it only shows the php pages statistic.

So, where should I look in Google Analytics?  and do I need to set up anything in GA for tracking the ajax call for 'importantpage' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling urchin within you AJAX function.  Like :

```
function callPage(div,params, page)  
    { 

        Facebook.urchinTracker(page);    

        var ajax_content = new Ajax();
        ajax_content.responseType = Ajax.FBML;
        ajax_content.ondone = function(data) 
            { 
                document.getElementById(div).setInnerFBML(data); 
            }
        var params={"Params":params,"target":div};        
        ajax_content.post(page,params);     

    }
```